# change fields in materialized view - oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Goodnight,

I have a working materialized view,to which I will add 15 left join similar to the ones in the example lines below, is there a way to edit it and hide the rowids?,If I replace the rowid with primary key, could I omit them?

because I would have to put 15 additional rowids, and it would be visually impractical. is there a way to make it only show the fields I want and not the rowsid,

How else could I change it to not have unnecessary columns, is there a way to handle incremental loads without having to do all a complex stored procedures?
this way is quite simple for handling incremental loads, it is mandatory that the materialized view be incremental (refresh fast)

thank you very much.
Regards.

```
create materialized view vm_prueba2

refresh fast on demand

with rowid as

select 
   o.rowid o_rowid,
   c.rowid c_rowid,
   e.rowid e_rowid,
   ordenid,
   o.empleadoid,
   o.clienteid,
   fechaorden,
   descuento,
   nvl(c.desccripcion,'') as ddesc,
   e.desccripcion

from ordenes o, tabla_hija c, tabla_hija e

where
 
  ( o.clienteid=c.valor(+) and c.id_tabla=1 or c.valor is null ) and
   ( o.empleadoid=e.valor(+) and e.id_tabla=2 or e.valor is null )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- create a materialized view, with all the `rowid`s
- create a **view** on a top on that materialized view which shows only columns you want

  - that way, you'd "hide" everything you don't need (`rowid`s, right?)

    - which also means that you'd actually use the view in selects, not the materialized view
  - materialized view refresh would work *as usual*

For example:

```
create materialized view vm_prueba2
  refresh fast on demand
  with rowid as
select 
   o.rowid o_rowid,
  ...
from ...;

-- a view would select only some columns from the materialized view:
create or replace view v_vm_prueba2 as
  select empleadoid,
         clienteid,
         fechaorden
from vm_prueba2;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I do not know if you can tell me a very small example, it is not very clear to me, I create two views, a materialized view with the rowid, and a normal view that calls the materialized view??, thanks

Comment: Exactly, that's what I meant. I posted an example, have a look.